# Determine date and time from a fixed date given seconds elapsed since fixed date in python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I need to determine a date given the seconds elapsed since said date.

I have the date in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` and I am aware that it can be converted to a `datetime.datetime()` object as a good starting point but how can I use a date time object as a reference point and accurately derive the date by extrapolating a given number of seconds?

Comment: So basically you want something like '2017-05-04 02:00:05' + 1542011 seconds -> new Date object?

Comment: If you have the value of seconds, you can get the datetime object from a base date with `timedelta`, somthing like this `new_date = base_date_object + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)`. do you need this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `timedelta` of the datetime module like this:

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 19, 15, 0, 0)

new_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=5*86400)
## adds 5 days = 5*86400 seconds
print(new_date)
```

Give the output

```
2017-10-24 15:00:00
```